# CSV output from PowerShell (test-connection) appearing blank when more than one line in source CSV

Tags: powershell, csv

I am running below script:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"
$servers = import-csv 'config-network devicetest.csv'
$collection = $()
foreach ( $IPAddress in $servers)
{
$status = @{ "ServerName" = $servers.HostName; "TimeStamp" = (Get-Date -f s) }
if (Test-Connection -IPAddress $servers.IPAddress -Count 1 -ea 0 -quiet)
{ 
    $status["Results"] = "Active"
} 
else 
{ 
    $status["Results"] = "Inactive" 
}
New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $status -OutVariable serverStatus
$collection += $serverStatus

}
$collection | Export-Csv .\ServerStatus.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

If I have one line in the CSV file that has a hostname and an IPaddress(to ping)
the output is as expected.

**TimeStamp               Results   ServerName**

**2014-09-10T12:57:23         Active    Server1 (for example)**

when i add an additional IPaddress and Hostname on the next line all i get is a blank result and servername; with a timestamp.

Currently fairly new to import/exporting of CSV stuff and also been a while since I've delved into powershell. what am I missing to make multiple entries (I have a CSV with thousands of IP addresses and hostnames) appear like the one above?

I've also tried adding the -delay parameter into the test-connection command but this has no effect (whilst running it doesn't appear to have any delay).
Also I've added in erroractionpreference (for any blank fields in $IPaddress column).

Any help would be appreciated as I'm stumped on this.

Comment: an example input would be

IPAddress,Hostname

74.125.237.175,Google


to output as active and hostname = Google

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your foreach-loop, replace $servers with $IPAddress

Comment: Doesn't work. because of $servers = import-csv. need it to run test-connection on each line in the source csv file. the code works when there only one source input (one line) but doesn't work when it has to do multiple.

Comment: What I mean is, replace this:
`$status = @{ "ServerName" = $servers.HostName; "TimeStamp" = (Get-Date -f s) }
if (Test-Connection -IPAddress $servers.IPAddress -Count 1 -ea 0 -quiet)`

with

`$status = @{ "ServerName" = $IPAddress.HostName; "TimeStamp" = (Get-Date -f s) }
if (Test-Connection -IPAddress $IPAddress.IPAddress -Count 1 -ea 0 -quiet)`

Comment: Oh yes, sorry i completely understand now. Haven't used csv imports very much with powershell at all so still trying to get the syntax down. this has fixed the problem and outputs all the fields. thanks!

Comment: No sweat, glad you got it to work. Just a quick tip: Whenever I have a collection/array of servers and doing a foreach-loop, I tend to use `foreach($server in $servers)`. This makes the code in inside the loop make a little more sense. So in your code you would reference $server.Hostname instead of $IPAddress.Hostname (which don't really make much sense, right?)

Comment: Yep gotcha! was trying to hard to match things with my column names.